# Page Lifecycle API

Tags: javascript, html, page-lifecycle

[This article about Page Lifecycle API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/page-lifecycle-api) states that a webpage comes in Passive state when it has "A page is in the passive state if it is visible and does not have input focus."

I don't understand how come a page is visible but does not have input focus. How's that possible?

Comment: Simply when you click either on an other application or just an other window, the `document.visibilityState` is still "visible", but you don't have focus (the blur event fired)

Comment: Another ex: if i put the cursor in the address bar of the *browser*, the browser has the focus, not the open web page.

Comment: Think about it...it's possible to have more than one window visible in your screen at the same time, yes? e.g. the browser, and another program such as Notepad. So if you're focusing on Notepad, then the web page is visible but not focused. Simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/page-lifecycle-api#event-focus) you posted:

"Note: A focus event does not necessarily signal a state change. It only signals a state change if the page did not previously have input focus."

Also from [MDN about the focus event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event), "The focus event fires when an element has received focus. The main difference between this event and focusin is that focusin bubbles while focus does not.

The opposite of focus is blur."

Basically, its when someone starts interacting with the page.